# How to perform function on certain columns and then perform another function on that

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

Say that I have these data:

```
a <- data.frame(group=c("one", "two", "three"), a = c(1,2,3), b=c(4,3,5), c=c(8,2,1))

  group a b c
1   one 1 4 8
2   two 2 3 2
3 three 3 5 1
```

I would like to perform a function on the 2nd-4th columns and then perform another function on those results. In particular, I would like to square each of these columns, and then add the results together.

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
  group a b c want
1   one 1 4 8   81
2   two 2 3 2   17
3 three 3 5 1   35
```

(For the first row, `81` is obtained by `1^2 + 4^2 + 8^2`.

I have a sense that this might involve something like `lapply`, but I am not sure.

Note that I would like to do this using something other than something like

```
a %>% mutate(want = a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
```

(as in principle there could be thousands of columns to consider).

Solutions in base R as well as tidyverse are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `select` the columns, get the power and `reduce` to return the sum

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
a %>%
     mutate(want = select(cur_data(), -group)^2 %>% 
                  reduce(`+`))
```

-output

```
  group a b c want
1   one 1 4 8   81
2   two 2 3 2   17
3 three 3 5 1   35
```

---

Or use `rowSums`

```
a %>% 
    mutate(want = rowSums(select(cur_data(), -group)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
   group a b c want
1   one 1 4 8   81
2   two 2 3 2   17
3 three 3 5 1   35
```

---

Or if the function used is other than `^`, can also loop `across` the columns and then add (`+`) with `reduce` or use `rowSums`

```
a %>% 
    mutate(want = rowSums(across(-group, ~ .^2)))
  group a b c want
1   one 1 4 8   81
2   two 2 3 2   17
3 three 3 5 1   35
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
a$want <- rowSums(a[-1]^2)
```

gives

```
> a
  group a b c want
1   one 1 4 8   81
2   two 2 3 2   17
3 three 3 5 1   35
```